# Module not found: Can't resolve '@react-three/cannon'

Tags: reactjs, react-three-fiber

I cannot for the life of me figure out why I keep getting this error. It more than likely being a simple oversight is making it that much worse.

I created a new React app using CRA, installed `@react-three/fiber, @react-three/cannon`, and three, and copied the code example from the use-cannon docs into my App component to play around with. But, I keep getting this error. I've tried re-installing the package but that did nothing. I tried scrapping the app and starting a new one. Nothing. I'm getting the same error using code sandbox, too.

My **package.json** dependencies look like this:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@react-three/cannon": "^2.6.0",
    "@react-three/drei": "^7.3.1",
    "@react-three/fiber": "^7.0.6",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.14.1",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.2.7",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.8.3",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.3",
    "three": "^0.131.3",
    "web-vitals": "^1.1.2"
  }
```

And my **App.js** looks like this:

```
import React from "react";
import { Canvas } from "@react-three/fiber";
import { Physics, usePlane, useBox } from "@react-three/cannon";

function Plane(props) {
  const [ref] = usePlane(() => ({ rotation: [-Math.PI / 2, 0, 0], ...props }));
  return (
    <mesh ref={ref}>
      <planeBufferGeometry args={[100, 100]} />
    </mesh>
  );
}

function Cube(props) {
  const [ref] = useBox(() => ({ mass: 1, position: [0, 5, 0], ...props }));
  return (
    <mesh ref={ref}>
      <boxBufferGeometry />
    </mesh>
  );
}

const App = () => {
  return (
    <Canvas>
      <Physics>
        <Plane />
        <Cube />
      </Physics>
    </Canvas>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just noticed new release of `@react-three/cannon 2.6.0` is faulty. try downgrade version of `@react-three/cannon` to `2.5.0` and error will be gone. I saw the same error and fixed it by changing the version. we may need to raise an issue at r3f github repository.

running demo:

(the demo with r3f cannon 2.5.0)

https://codesandbox.io/s/elegant-sinoussi-zjzhj?file=/src/Cube.tsx